# PHP Classes - global or __construct

Tags: php, class

So I've come across a "problem" with PHP classes.

I have a few classes that require functions from one another, so at the moment I am doing the following:

```
$db = new blueConnect;
$core = new blueCore($db);
$users = new blueUsers($db, $core);
```

then within the file:

```
public function __construct(blueConnect $db, blueCore $core) {
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->core = $core;
}
```

However instead of doing this for each file that required additional functions, would it be better to write

```
global $db, $core
```

within each of the functions that require it?

Comment: Yes. Thus by you can avoid passing those as parameters.

Comment: So you would both recommend global? The only reason I did not want to use it was because in one class, many functions required $db for example, so using the __construct method seemed like the best alternative..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Name of the Pattern that you are talking about is called "**Dependency Injection**" or **DI** in short.

Depending on your Project using global might solve the problem in a short term but if you plan to create a big project that you later on test and share with multiple people you would like to avoid using global at all. - *You can not test or debug that stuff well*.

A (bad) solution is to make your database and core Class use the **Singleton Pattern** to avoid global but have the same effect. (*not testable, not configurable*)

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->db = blueConnect::getInstance();
    $this->core = blueCore::getInstance();
}
```

The solution for this is usually to create a **Factory function** that creates all of your **Services** that need the Database and the Core.

```
public function createService($name) {
    $serviceClass = 'blue'.ucfirst($name).'Service';
    return new $serviceClass($this->getDatabase(), $this->getCore());
}
```

And this Function is usually part of a **Registry** or better an **DI Container** like for example [PIMPLE](https://github.com/fabpot/Pimple/blob/master/src/Pimple/Container.php)

**Example with Only one Instance of each Service:**

```
public function createService($name) {
    $serviceClass = 'blue'.ucfirst($name).'Service';

    static $services = array();
    if(!isset($services[$name])) {
        $services[$name] = new $serviceClass($this->getDatabase(), $this->getCore());
    }

    return $services[$name];
}
```

Be aware that you should NOT test with your Registry / DI Container since you have a "global" state inside of your container. (e.g. fetching the same service twice)

Comment: This [series of articles](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection) might complement your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm a bit confused with how a factory function works though. On the return line of your sample code, would that create a new instance for the class each time the function is called? And where would such a function be placed?

Comment: The Function is usually part of the **DI-Container** since there should be also the possibility to call getDatabase() etc. With PIMPLE there are examples how you would only create one Service of each type and return it if requested for a second time.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use globals.

Reasons:

1. It's just not the [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) way.
2. Hard to debug.
3. The resulting code would not be testable. If you want your application to be covered by unit tests you should use [Dependcy Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) as you currently do. I'll try to briefly explain why. Unit testing as its name implies is just that: testing a single unit of your application, i.e. your classes (their `public` methods).

   Now let's suppose you use global variables that get set somewhere in your app. You won't be able to test your `blueUsers` class as a standalone unit because you will need the `$db` and `$core` objects to be instantiated. Therefore you won't be able to just include the `blueUsers.php` file and test the class because you will need other parts of your application (those which define the global variables `$db` and `$core`).

   If on the other hand you used [Dependcy Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) you wouldn't face such an issue. The only things you'll need to do in order to test the `blueUsers` class would be to include the class, create mocks of the dependencies `$db` and `$core`, and pass them to the `blueUsers` constructor.

Here's a nice [source](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-write-testable-and-maintainable-code-in-php--net-31726) for more detailed explanation on how to write testable and maintainable code.

And [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html) you could find more information about mocking and whether and what you can benefit from using it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a singletone to contain the global objects. It's easily accessible by other objects and it provides a safe access to those variables:

```
final class GlobalObjects
{
    public static function Instance()
    {
        static $inst = null;
        if ($inst === null) {
            $inst = new GlobalObjects();
        }
        return $inst;
    }

    private function __construct() {
        $db = new blueConnect;
        $core = new blueCore($db);
    }

    public function getDb() { return $this->db; }

    public function getCore() { return $this->core; }
}

// ...

public function __construct() {
    $this->db = GlobalObjects::Instance()->getDb();
    $this->core = GlobalObjects::Instance()->getCore();
}
```

Another approach that comes into my mind, a simpler and dirtier one, is: as those variables are global objects it might be worth to define them as constants to avoid mistakes:

```
define( "db", new blueConnect );
define( "core", new blueCore($db) );

$users = new blueUsers($db, $core);
```

And then

```
public function __construct() {
    global $db, $core;

    $this->db = $db;
    $this->core = $core;
}
```

Comment: I love the final part of your response, dirty but it works ;) I never thought about including the global $db, $core inside of __construct! With the singleton method, does that create a new db, core each time the GlobalObjects class is called?

Comment: No. A singletone is an object that can exists only once (one instance maximum) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern. So the new db is created only once and returned every time you call getDb()

Comment: I'm puzzled by those constants that you don't use.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameters are dynamic and variable, you should pass them in constructor, so new `blueUsers($db, $core, ...)` is better. But if these are static parameter, and you don't need to pass them when initialization of the class, you should define as global.

Comment: Thanks for the info! At the moment, $db is not static and is used for the database side of things, whereas $core contains only static functions, so should $db be passed via __construct and $core through global?

Comment: An alternative to global would be to have a factory for $db and $core (or if they're singletons) that could be called from within blueUsers to return the existing instances